# Populating data : uncaught syntaxerror unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript

I have a form inside an iframe, and I'd like to prepopulate the form with certain data.

I'm trying to use php and javascript to accomplish this.

My code looks something like this :

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(window).load(function() {
          document.getElementById('20988888993483').document.getElementById('input_13').value = <?=htmlspecialchars($_POST['input_13'])?>;
      }
  </script>
```

the id of the iframe is 20988888993483, and the ID of the input is input_13. I preload the value from previous form submission.

This code is strung together though, and I'm not quite sure what to do.

The error I get when I load the javascript is : `uncaught syntaxerror unexpected end of input`

**UPDATE**

Along with people's suggestions, I've added quotes around the PHP string. In the wild, with the value being 5, the javascript looks like this -- >

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(window).load(function() {
        document.getElementById('20988888993483').document.getElementById('input_13').value = "5";
      }
  </script>
```

I still get the error though. Thoughts greatly appreciated

Comment: Try to add quotes: `... = "<?=...?>";`

Comment: Did you try to put the PHP part inside quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data in `$_POST['input_13']` is a string (ie: not numeric or `null`), then you need to enclose it in quotes.

To handle the possibility of the [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) configuration setting being enabled:

```
$strValue = $_POST['input_13'];
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $strValue = stripslashes($strValue);
}
```

You then need to escape double-quotes only:

```
$strValue = addcslashes($strValue, '"');
```

The string is now safe to insert into the JavaScript. Also note that there's no need to use `htmlspecialchars()`, since you're setting the `value` property of the element, not the `innerHTML` property.

```
document.getElementById('20988888993483').document.getElementById('input_13').value = "<?= $strValue ?>";
```

**Edit**

Alternatively, if you're running PHP >= 5.2.0, then the best solution is to use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
$strValue = $_POST['input_13'];
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $strValue = stripslashes($strValue);
}

document.getElementById('20988888993483').document.getElementById('input_13').value = <?= json_encode($strValue) ?>;
```

Comment: Ohp, that makes sense. I added that, though the error still seems to persist. I've updated the post with how it looks like at the moment. Your thoughts very much appreciated.

Comment: Ohp! just needed to add }); at the bottom of the javascript as well. All is well! Thank you :)